# SQLAlchemy One-to-Many query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am confused about how to do a query. I have the following declaration

```
class GrandParent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "grandparent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(16))
    # One-to-one relationship
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", backref=backref("grandparent", uselist=False))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(16))
    # One-to-many relationship
    children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(16))
    index = Column(Integer)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))

    def __init__(self, name, idx):
        self.name = name
        self.index = idx

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

What I'd like to be able to do is querying for a `Child` object knowing its `index` and `GrandParent.id`. I know this query does not work but just to illustrate what I'm looking for:

```
c = session.query(Child).filter(Child.parent.grandparent.id == 2 and Child.index == 3).first()
```

> AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor
>   'Comparator' object associated with Child.parent has an attribute
>   'grandparent'

However this works:

```
grandparent = GrandParent('dad')
grandparent.parent = Parent('bob')
grandparent.parent.children.append(Child('alice', 1))
grandparent.parent.children.append(Child('jo', 2))
grandparent.parent.children.append(Child('blo', 3))
foo = Child('foo', 4)
grandparent.parent.children.append(foo)
session.add(grandparent)
print(foo.grandparent.parent.id)
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally found a solution juste after posting.

See [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-exists) for reference

```
c = session.query(Child).\
        filter(Child.parent.has(Parent.grandparent.has(GrandParent.id == 2))).\
        filter(Child.index == 2).first()
```